# Accessing external MySQL instance from application deployed on Kubernetes

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes

In a project, I am using kubernetes with mysql.

Till now, for sake of POC, I have made it work by setting up mysql in one of the pod and loading the DB dump to the associated DB as follows:

```
docker exec -i <CONTAINER NAME> mysql -uroot -p<PASSWORD> <DATABASE NAME>< /path/to/dump.sql
```

But to deploy it, I need to use external MySQL instance. Can anyone please help me regarding this ?

Comment: Hey, if you are trying to access an MySQL instance managed externally from within a k8s cluster (each in their own VPC), this article should be of help [Accessing Amazon RDS From AWS EKS](https://dev.to/bensooraj/accessing-amazon-rds-from-aws-eks-2pc3). Disclaimer: I am the author of the article. Though the context is AWS, I am pretty sure the steps are more or less transferable to any cloud provider.

Comment: What have you tried already?  What doesn't work?  There shouldn't be anything unusual about accessing a database out-of-cluster.